# Array value find using index partial string using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am having below array. I would like to get the value which is having '1' and the key should be 'wf_status_step%'. How to write a PHP script for this?

```
[ini_desc] => 31.07 Initiative1
[mea_id] => 1
[status] => 4
[name] => 31.07 Measure1
[scope] => NPR
[sector] => 
[mea_commodity] => 8463
[commodity_cls] => IT
[delegate_usrid] => 877
[wf_status_step1] => 2
[wf_status_step2] => 1
[wf_status_step3] => 0
[wf_status_step4] => 0
[wf_status_step5] => 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shorter version that will find all keys with value 1 that start with 'wf_status_step'

```
$keys = array_filter(array_keys($array,1),function($key){
    return stripos($key,'wf_status_step') === 0;
});
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but that's only half the problem. The OP still needs to iterate over the founds keys and see which one has the desired value.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm the second argument to [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) takes care of that

Comment: Oh, nice. I didn't even realize that. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer

```
foreach($your_array as $key=>$value)
{
  if(strpos($key, 'f_status_step') !== FALSE) // will check for existence of "f_status_step" in the keys
  {
     if($value == 1) // if the value of that key is 1
     {
       // this is your target item in the array
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: But that will also match keys like "this_is_the_wrong_key_wf_status_step". Isn't it better to check that `strpos` actually returns 0?

Comment: Yes that would, but going by the keys present in the OP's array, this will work fine. Of course, the OP didn't mention that the keys might be differ too

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys in the array to find all the keys that match your pattern, and simulatenously check associated values. Something like this:

```
<?php
$found_key = null;
foreach(array_keys($my_array) as $key) {
    if(strpos($key, "wf_status_step") === 0) {
        //Key matches, test value.
        if($my_array[$key] == 1) {
            $found_key = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if( !is_null($found_key) ) {
    //$found_key is the one you're looking for
} else {
    //Not found.
}
?>
```

If you want to be more sophisticated about matching the key, you can use regular expressions.

You can also use the `foreach($my_array as $key=>$value)` mechanism that is shown in some other answers, instead of using `array_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array_name as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($key, 'wf_status_step') === 0) {
    if ($value == 1) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But that will also match keys like "this_is_the_wrong_key_wf_status_step". Isn't it better to check that `strpos` actually returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $wf_status_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value === 1 && preg_match_all('~^wf_status_step[0-9]+$~',$key,$res)){
            $key = $res[0][0];
            $wf_status_array[$key] = $array[$key];
        }
    }
    print_r($wf_status_array)
```